# Kotlin - Get static functions with reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection, static-methods, companion-object

I was using this piece of code to map all static functions of a Java class to stuff:

```
fun staticsFromClass(clazz: Class<*>): List<Something> = clazz.methods
        .filter { method -> Modifier.isStatic(method.modifiers) }
        .map { method ->
           //something
        }
```

but I found out it only works on Java code. It filters out companion object functions and singleton object functions. How can I fix it?

Comment: To Java, an `object` is just a regular class with no static members (except `const val`s might be compiled as static fields, not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this code works with Kotlin classes, but usually Kotlin does not have any static members. You can acquire companion members with the following code:

```kotlin
fun companionMembersFromClass(clazz: KClass<*>): List<Something> {
    val members = clazz.companionObject?.members ?: emptyList()
    ...
}
```

Similarly, you can acquire the instance of the companion with: `clazz.companionObjectInstance`.

Alternatively, you can reference a companion class directly with e.g.: `MyClass.Companion::class` and then list its non-static members.